# Automatic first letter to upper case?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying replace first letter of the text in a cell to upper case when a cell edited. For that I'm using `onEdit` script trigger:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  e.range.setValue(e.range.getValue().replace(/^./, a => a.toUpperCase()));
}
```

It works well, until I try undo in the spreadsheet, than `onEdit` fires again and replaces the text again.

So is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

#### First Letter to UpperCase

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(/^\s*(\w)/, a => a.toUpperCase()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's practically the same I'm using and it also creates an extra entry into edit history (undo) even when no text changed (i.e. typed word with capital first letter)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the event object that `onEdit` receives contains `value` and `oldValue` properties, they both set to `undefined` when used undo.

So this seems to be working much better (it also ignores white space infront):

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  if (e.value)
  {
    const val = e.value.replace(/^\s*./, a => a.toUpperCase());
    if (val !== e.value)
      e.range.setValue(val);
  }
}
```

It still not a perfect solution, because it has delay in the execution and also it might skip cells if multiple edits in multiple cells were done in short period of time.